# How we can have dependency injection in laravel package

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, package, repository-pattern

I develop the Laravel package and I want to use Repository Pattern and put services in it and then inject this Repository to my Controller.

Pay attention that I need a solution in package development.

Comment: Maybe create a service provider and follow Facade pattern. What approach have you followed so far?

Comment: I did it and in "register" method of serviceProvider I linked my Interface to concrete class but I got error that said The class connot be found .

Comment: It's impossible to know what your problem might be without a minimal example that we can use to reproduce it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may define the provider in the extra section of your package's composer.json file. In addition to service providers, you may also list any facades you would like to be registered:

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "providers": [
            "Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\ServiceProvider"
        ],
        "aliases": {
            "Debugbar": "Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Facade"
        }
    }
},
```

source: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/packages#package-discovery

Comment: Its good idea to use Facade but I want write an Interface and implement it with concrete class and inject interface to controller. Do you mean I should link interface and class in serviceprovider?

Comment: @akbar yea, you should define your dependency injection in your service provider and that's it you can inject it into your controllers or wherever you want

Comment: ohhhhh yes.  I had misspelling in add provider in my servicProvider.tnx a lot